# Google Analytics User Id doesn't take utm_ (acquisition) parameters into account

Tags: google-analytics

I have implemented the following process to track User ID on my website:

1. If the user is not yet logged in, track a pageview
2. Once he registers or logs in, set user id and keep setting it on every page

I have session unification turned on.

It works OK except that in the "user id" view, I see 100% of acquisition surce/medium as (direct) / (none), but in "all data" though, the utm_ parameters for the same session have been tracked correctly.

I would like to see which campaign was each given user acquired by, but because of this, I am not seeing that.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found the answer in the docs eventually:

> Session unification is completed during daily data processing. Processing begins at 5am each day, based on the western most timezone selected in any reporting view that is associated with the property.

Looks like I have everything set up right, just need to wait for the recalculation.

Comment: Can you update us if this was indeed the cause ? Thank you.

Comment: Yes it was, I checked this morning and the data appeared there :)